# Excel VBA macro reading one column with differing text

Tags: excel, string, vba

I was tasked with creating a code that will check to see if internal hyperlinks in an excel spreadsheet worked. This code first changes the formulas that were on the spreadsheet and makes them actual hyperlinks (they were originally formulas linking the locations together). The problem that I have now is that I want to create hyperlinks **ONLY** if Column S has text. If it doesn't, I don't want the "E-COPY" text to be displayed. All of the text in Column S varies (not one line has the same characters), which is why I'm drawing a blank is to how I tell the program to only continue if it has any text, not anything specific. I am working with Excel 2016.

Also, I am doing this to 71935 and counting rows; is there a limit to how many it can go through? If so, what can I do about it?

Thank you!

```
Sub CreateHyperlinks()
Dim FN As Variant

Dim Path As Variant
Dim count As Variant

Sheets(1).Activate
count = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets(1).Range("A:A"))


For i = 2 To count

If Range("AM" & i).Value = "Yes" And Columns("S") =  Then 
Range("E" & i).Value = ""

Path = Sheets(1).Range("R" & i).Value
FN = Sheets(1).Range("S" & i).Value


    Sheets(1).Range("E" & i).Select
    Selection.ClearFormats
    Selection.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:=Path & FN, TextToDisplay:="E-COPY"

    Range("AM" & i).Value = " "

End If

Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Any text in S vs. empty? or vs. a number/date/etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to check for any content in ColS then:

```
If Range("AM" & i).Value = "Yes" And Len(Range("S" & i).Value) > 0 Then
```

Answer (score 2):

Few things:

```
'make a reference to the sheet you're working with
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = Excel.Application.ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)

'gets the absolute last row with data in it // ignores empty cells
count = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

personally, i hate working with named ranges, so i would suggest setting range references like so

what you wrote

```
Path = Sheets(1).Range("R" & i).Value
```

what i believe it should look like

```
Path = ws.Cells(i, 18).Value
```

if you want to test the type when working with variants, try this:

```
'tests the type associated with the variant. an 8 = string
If VarType(ws.Cells(i, 19).Value) = 8 Then
    'do your thing

'tests if the value is null
ElseIf VarType(ws.Cells(i, 19).Value) = 0 Then
    'do your other thing
```

[here's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/vartype-function) a list of the vartype enumeration to help you out.

hope it helps!

Comment: Couldn't reply to your previous ping (answer was deleted), so here: yes, I *did* read that link which I fetched from my bookmarks - the now-deleted question was closed by myself and the moderator that handled the NAA flag I cast on the answer. Not sure what you were insinuating there.

Comment: Now while I'm here, why not use the `VbVarType` enum members (defined in the VBA standard library), instead of using magic numbers and comments to explain them? `vbString` is self-explanatory, `8` isn't. ;-)

Comment: Basically, I copied from the article you linked and in summary it said that bad questions elicit bad answers. I mean, there are numerous ways to skin a cat, and if the person is asking "how do i skin a cat? i have no experience" then the reasonable answer is to give them relevant tutorials.

Comment: That's the nice thing to do, indeed - and with 73 rep the author of that answer should have done that in a comment while highlighting that the question is off-topic ;-)

Comment: True that vbString is self-explanatory, however I prefer to use numbers instead of text. Just my thing.

Comment: Side node, that `If VarType(...)` would probably be better as a `Select Case VarType(...)` with `Case vbString` and `Case vbNull` blocks. #SkinningTheCat cheers, hope you stick around - the VBA tag needs some love!

Comment: Yeah it probably would cut down on how much one needs to write. I almost never use Select Cases for some reason. In this instance I agree that it would be more efficient than an If statement. I was initially surprised with how much attention there is to VBA coming from C++.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176903/discussion-between-mathieu-guindon-and-jcrizk).